# R+Tableau connection: Using linear regression & Relaimpo package; Working in R but not in connection

Tags: r, tableau-api

I am applying a linear regression model to data, and using the relaimpo package to find the most significant factors.

When running the following code in R, it works fine

```
library(readxl)
nba <- read_excel("XXXX")
View(nba)


library(relaimpo)
rec = lm(won ~ o_fgm + o_ftm + o_pts , data = nba)
x= calc.relimp(rec, type = c("lmg"), rela = TRUE, rank = TRUE)
x$lmg
```

I get output of:

```
    o_fgm     o_ftm     o_pts 
0.3374366 0.2628543 0.3997091
```

When connecting via Tableau I use the following code:

```
SCRIPT_REAL("
won=.arg1
o_fgm=.arg2
o_ftm=.arg3
o_pts=.arg4


library(relaimpo)
rec = lm(won ~ o_fgm + o_ftm + o_pts)
x= calc.relimp(rec, type = c('lmg'), rela = TRUE, rank = TRUE)

"
,MEDIAN([Won]),MEDIAN([O Fgm]),MEDIAN([O Ftm]),MEDIAN([O Pts]))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
An error occurred while communicating with the RServe service.
Error in calc.relimp.default.intern(object = structure(list(won = 39, : Too few complete observations for estimating this model
```

I have run it with just the regression and it runs fine; so it seems the issue is with the relaimpo package. There is limited documentation online on this package so I cannot find a fix; any help is really appreciated thanks!

Data is from kaggle at https://www.kaggle.com/open-source-sports/mens-professional-basketball

(the "basketball_teams.csv" file)

Comment: The formulas in those two cases are different.

Comment: Updated: I have been playing around with a lot of different version so copied the wrong one in. Any variation of number of variables produces the same error.

Answer (score 1):

When Tableau calls R or Python using the SCRIPT_REAL() function, or any SCRIPT_XXX() function, it is using what Tableau calls a table calculation. This has the effect of passing R one or more vectors -- and receiving back vector results -- instead of calling the function once for each scalar cell.

However, you are responsible for specifying how to partition your aggregate results into vectors, and how to order the rows in  the vectors you send to R or Python. You do that by specifying the "partitioning" and "addressing" of each table calc via the Edit Table Calc command (right click on a calc field).

So the most likely issue, is that you are sending R less data than you expect, perhaps many short vectors instead of the one long one you intend. Read about Table Calcs and partitioning and addressing in the online help. You specify partitioning in particular by the choice of which dimensions are *not* set to "compute using" (a synonym for addressing dimensions) The Table Calc editor gives you some visible feedback as you try different settings - I recommend using specific dimensions in most cases.

For table calcs, the choice of partitioning and addressing is as important as the actual formula.